# Read Excel worksheet using COM API by Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have used xlrd and xlwt earlier where its easy to read rows and column. I am in a process to convert my current excel read and write code(which is currently using xlrd and xlwt) to excel com api.

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wbtemp = excel.Workbooks.Open(file path)
readtemp = wbtemp.Worksheets('Temp')
read_1 = readtemp.Cells(1,1)
print read_1
System User

used = readtemp.UsedRange
print used.Find('System User')
System User ## it shows System User is present in worksheet, wont give which cell

print used.Find('xyz')
None ## when its not found on worksheet
```

Currently above code is hard coded to Cell (1,1), but i am looking for flexible method like search for 'System User' in worksheet and get reply as Cell (1,1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wbtemp = excel.Workbooks.Open(file path)
readtemp = wbtemp.Worksheets('Temp')
read_1 = readtemp.Cells(1,1)
print read_1
System User

used = readtemp.UsedRange
a = used.Rows.Find('System User')
print a.Address
$A$1 ## Thats what I was looking for..
```